# Не могу изменить пароль пользователя mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

```
use mysql;
UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD("0000") where User='Admin3';
```

UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD("0000") where User='Admin3'    Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '("0000") where User='Admin3'' at line 1    0.000 sec

Вот такая возникает ошибка, что не правильно?

Comment: А если новый пароль заключить не в кавычки, а в апострофы?

Comment: А подскажите вашу версию MySQL?

Comment: версия MySql8.2

Comment: В 8, если правильно помню. ALTER USER 'Admin3'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '0000';

Comment: То есть я хочу сказать, что PASSWORD() - лишнее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том что все представленные ответы отчасти верны, за одной деталью. Начиная с версии 5.7 функция PASSWORD() - depricated.
[WL#6409](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=6409)
Так что надо:

```
SET PASSWORD [FOR user] = 'пароль';
```

или

```
ALTER USER 'user'@'host' IDENTIFIED BY 'пароль';
```

Answer (score 0):

Свой пароль можно поменять через:

```
SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('пароль')
```

Пароль определенного пользователя можно поменять через:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR логин@localhost = PASSWORD('пароль');
SET PASSWORD FOR логин@"%" = PASSWORD('пароль');
```

тоже самое делают:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('пароль') WHERE User='логин' AND Host='localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

или

```
GRANT USAGE ON БД.* TO логин@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'пароль';
```

или

```
mysqladmin -u логин password пароль
```

Comment: не работает: SET PASSWORD FOR User2@'%' = PASSWORD('0000'); ошибка 1064

Answer (score 0):

Для начала посмотреть всех пользователей:

```
SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;
```

Выбираем базу mysql:

```
use mysql;
```

Для меня всегда работала команда, которая обновит пароль у пользователя:

```
UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('новый пароль') WHERE User='ваш_логин' AND Host='ваш_хост';
```

Пароль должен быть сложным!

Comment: UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('password pass 00001 a') WHERE User='User2' AND Host='%'; не работает